# MSBuild .NET Core 3.1 application - Set PublishDir value in csproj

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, csproj, msbuild-propertygroup, publishdir

I struggle to set the PublishDir value in the new .net core 3.1 csproj format.
In the old csproj format I was able to set the value like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<PublishDir>..\test\path</PublishDir>
```

I was even able to use a Condition attribute in the PublishDir element to use different values depending on the build configuration.

Now with the new csproj I tried the same, but the PublishDir is still set to something like:
`bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/app.publish`.
Where does this directory come from?

Only when I add the parameter via msbuild call with /p:PublishDir="..\test\path" the application gets published in the appropriate directory.

Is there anything else I need to take into consideration? Do I need to set the value after a specific target, like PrepareForPublish?

Comment: None of the rules regarding property evaluation changed and setting properties still works as it used to in msbuild. So if a property doesn't get the excpected value, it gets overridden somewhere else, or whatever process you are using does not actually use that property, etc.. Hard to tell without seeing a complete project file and the steps used to build it.

Comment: I found a way by setting the PublishDir value in a custom target before the PrepareForPublish event. But it was necessary to read the PublishDir in an ItemGroup first, before I had access to change it actually. Unfortunately, you don't find this kind of information in any documentation. So, yes, it probably gets overwritten, if set at top in a PropertyGroup element with subelements like TargetFramework, etc. .

Comment: @kvirk - Could you answer your own question with the solution you found? Unfortunately, this comment isn't very helpful for those who want to find an answer to this.

Comment: @NightOwl888: Thanks for your comment, I have just added the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I had mentioned in the comment before:

```
<Target Name="CustomPublishTarget" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  <ItemGroup>
      <PublishDir Include="$(PublishDir)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
      <PublishDir>..\test\path</PublishDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```